# How to forward traffic from an app in listening mode using reverse SSH tunnel?

Tags: ssh, proxy, port, ssh-tunnel

I have an scenario like this:

Host A (at-home computer): normally, I open port 4000 on the router, and my app listens on that port for connections.

Host B (at-work computer): I don't have access to the router, so I can't open port 4000 to listen. But I can establish a reverse ssh connection to host A. What I do is:

> ssh -g -R 4000:localhost:2000 user@hostA.IP.address

And then, on host B, my app listens on port 2000, but it doesn't receive any connections.

I already set "GatewayPorts" and "AllowTcpForwarding" to "yes" in "sshd_config" file. I don't know where am I wrong so can you guys help me out ?

Comment: you already configured router to make translation 4000->hostA:2000. so you need to map hostB:2000 to hostA:2000 for router to pass frames from WAP-IP:4000 to hostA:2000 and through tunnel to hostB:2000 , so you need to fix port number in your command  ```ssh -g -R 2000:localhost:2000 user@hostA.IP.address``` .

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny I have changed the command like you said, but it didn't work. Do I have to do anything with the router (so that it can redirect traffic from port 4000 to hostA:2000) ?

Comment: I rechecked your question and see that you did everything right - please ignore my advice. I wonder whether you missed warning during ssh connect ```Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 4000```. this could happen when hostA already runs service at port 4000 and you try to bind another service to the same port.

Comment: I just double check my configure, and I don't see any warning messages. But I see something strange. First, before I make a reverse ssh connect, I use my app on host A to listen on port 4000, and when I check on [canyouseeme](https://canyouseeme.org), it says my port is opening. Then I close the app, and make a reverse ssh connection, and check on canyouseeme again, it says port 4000 is not opening, but I'm sure that port 4000 is opening because at this time I use my app on host A and it says "Port 4000 is already in used".
"netstat -a" gives me:
TCP 0.0.0.04:000 Computer:0 LISTENING